# Mock class attribute with @patch decorator

Tags: python, mocking, patch, python-decorators

How can I mock a object property of a class under test with the `@patch` decorator?

Given following test:

```
def test_hangup(self):
    stub_call = Mock()

    cut = TelefonyInterface()
    cut.call = stub_call
    cut.hangup()

    self.assertEqual(1, stub_call.hangup.call_count)
    self.assertEqual(None, cut.call)
```

I'd like to use the `mock.patch` decorator here to make it bit easier to read. Something like this:

```
@patch.object(TelefonyInterface, 'call')
def test_hangup(self, call):
    cut = TelefonyInterface()
    cut.hangup()

    self.assertEqual(1, call.hangup.call_count)
    self.assertEqual(None, cut.call)
```

But I get the following AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: <class '(...).TelefonyInterface'> does not have the attribute 'call'
```

My TelefonyInterface looks something like this:

```
class TelefonyInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.call = None

    def dial(self, number):
        self.call = ...

    def hangup(self):
        if self.call:
            self.call.hangup()

    ...
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are patching the `TelefonyInterface` class, which does not have an attribute `call`. That attribute is defined on the instance at initialization time. To accomplish what you want patch the instance instead of the class:

```
def test_hangup(self):
    cut = TelefonyInterface()
    with patch.object(cut, 'call') as call:
        cut.hangup()

        self.assertEqual(1, call.hangup.call_count)
        self.assertEqual(None, cut.call)
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, that makes sense. :)